# In cross tab crystal report formula not access current filed value coresponding value of another column

Tags: asp.net

In Cross tab crystal report formula,

Datatable values

math   phy

76     87

65     88

67     64

I write following Formula :

if(tonumber(CurrentFieldValue)>0) then (

if(tonumber({ReportDataTable.phy})>0) then

crgreen

else

crred
)

else

crred

here first time two if condition correctly check and execute, but second time first if of currentfieldvalue  take 65 of math column value but inner if loop "{ReportDataTable.phy}"
take again first row of phy column value 87 not 88. And also third time execution take 87 not 64

Please help me...